# Print complex python variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am trying to print in `console.log()` my `series` variable but no success so far.

```
def multiple_series(res):
    matrix = dict(res)
    all_cat_keys = set(key[0] for key in matrix)
    categories = sorted(all_cat_keys)
    all_series_keys = set(key[1] for key in matrix)
    series = [
        {
            'name': series_key,
            'data': [
                [cat_key, matrix.get((cat_key, series_key), 0)]
                for cat_key in categories
            ],
        }
        for series_key in all_series_keys
    ]
    return series
```

I've tried using `json.dumps()` and the well known `console.log({{ series }})` but I get nothing.

I'd like to print the content of `name` and `data`. Can anyone help me ? I don't have much experience using JS. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is posted corretly? the for look don't look loke they woudl belong there. Do you have a solid background in Python? What output do you exspect?

Comment: I am sure that `multiple_series()` method is correct. I am expecting some json output containing some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log({{ series }})` can not work because `{{ series }}` gets evaluated to text. Therefore JS thinks it's a JS object.

Add quotes around the object to treat it as text and it should work:

```
console.log("{{ series }}");
```

Comment: @Leistungsabfall I still get nothing. I should let the `return series` as it is ? Or I should transform it so that it will return a JSON ?

Comment: I thought `{{ series }}` was a template variable. Simply doing `return series` won't work. You have to include your code in a template and render it like this: `return render(request, 'template.html', {'series': series})`

Answer (score 1):

Iam not sure about your input data - but you are building the series list the wrong way. You should build you `series` list like that:

```
def multiple_series(res):
    matrix = dict(res)
    all_cat_keys = set(key[0] for key in matrix)
    categories = sorted(all_cat_keys)
    all_series_keys = set(key[1] for key in matrix)

    series = []
    for series_key in all_series_keys:
        dict_to_add = {'name': series_key}
        data_information = []
        for cat_key in categories:
            data_information.append((cat_key, matrix.get((cat_key, series_key), 0)))
        dict_to_add['data'] = data_information
        series.append(dict_to_add)
    return series
```

Comment: I get this error `append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)` :)